# Epson TM T20 - Printing from web

Tags: css, jsf, printing, primefaces, epson

I've done a small system in jsf, ejb and primefaces for my client and he wants to print a receipt in his printer Epson TM-T20.

I did the installation of the printer, configured it and printed a word file, it printed all ok, printed until where there were no more characters, but when I try to print from web, a huge blak space is printed along with the document. I tried in chrome, safari, ie, firefox and opera to see if the problem was with the browser, it wasn't.

I also configured the printer to remove header/footer to check if it was the one causing it, also negative, it wasn't that. I tried configuring the page size, is not working either.

I have no more ideas, has anyone ever had this problem before or know about any hack that i have to implement to get this ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do so, unfortunately not with the epson drivers. The solution is quite simple though. I created a jar that calls:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().print(file);
```

From my web programm, when I the invoice print was required, I crate a temp file in pure txt and call the jar to print it.

About the epson documentation, i found very few things that would help. All the mocks are problematic, doesnt work, the same goes for the code examples and eclipse projects that it is available in their example page.

Regards.

Answer (score -3):

You should have to make any adjustments on printing!, You install the driver and PRINT! Page size and header and foot should be left alone. Do all of your printing for margins INSIDE YOUR PROGRAMMING and from there you should mess with it, setup how your layout is and be done